# Regex string between a double asterisk

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
What is **Sympathy.**
```

I'm attempting to create a regex statement that will find the string "Sympathy." between the double asterisk, including the double asterisk. However, I can't even figure out how to find the string between first.

This is what I've tried:

```
(?<=\\*\\*)(.*)(?=\\*\\*)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested this out and it worked

`\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}`

Breakdown

`\*{2}`- matches the character * literally (exactly 2 times)

`1st Capturing group (.*?)` - The quantifier will match it between 0 and unlimited times

`\*{2}`- matches the character * literally (exactly 2 times)

https://regex101.com/r/uQ0gJ1/1

Comment: Ah, so simple, yet so effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    \*{2}(.*?)\*{2}

    \*{2} -- matches double asterisks
    (.*?) -- captures anything, with "?" specifying non-greedy
```

Regex was tested here: https://regex101.com/